# ggplot2: scale_y_continuous number of ticks

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to increase number of ticks on my Y axis and don't know how can I achieve this.

This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/11335933/1286528) is helpful - suggests to use `scale_y_continuous(breaks = round(seq(min(dat$y), max(dat$y), by = 0.5),1))`.

Problem is that I am using `scale_y_continuous(limits = quantile(data, c(0.1, 0.9)))` command already and don't know where to add additional command for number of ticks.

Comment: You can add a `breaks = …` right after your `limits = …` since it's a separate parameter to `scale_y_continuous` which is really just a call to `continuous_scale`. Do a `?continuous_Scale` at an R console prompt to see the help on it which will show you all the possible parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `breaks = …` right after your `limits = …` since it's a separate parameter to `scale_y_continuous` which is really just a call to `continuous_scale`. Do a `?continuous_scale` at an R console prompt to see the help on it which will show you all the possible parameters.