# Limit ggplot2 axes without removing data (outside limits): zoom

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming, limits

If you specify axis limits in ggplot the outlying points are removed.  This is fine for points, but you might want to plot lines that intersect with the specified range, but ggplot's `range` or `xlim/ylim` methods removes these.  Is there another way to specify the plot axis range without removing outlying data?

e.g.

```
require(ggplot2)
d = data.frame(x=c(1,4,7,2,9,7), y=c(2,5,4,10,5,3), grp=c('a','a','b','b','c','c'))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + geom_line()
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + geom_line() + scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,7))
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + geom_line() + ylim(0,7)
```

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Hadley explains this on pp. 99; 133 of his [ggplot2 book (1st edition)](http://www.springer.com/statistics/computational+statistics/book/978-0-387-98140-6), or pp. 160 - 161 if you have the [second edition](http://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319242750).

The issue is that, as you say, `limits` inside the scale or setting [`ylim()`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/lims.html) causes data to be thrown away, as they are constraining the data.  For a true zoom (keep all the data), you need to set the limits inside of the Cartesian coordinate system (or other coordinate systems https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/#section-coordinate-systems).  For more see: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/coord_cartesian.html

```
ggplot(d, aes(x, y, group=grp)) + 
    geom_line() + 
    coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 7))
```

[image]

Comment: What if coord_cartesian is not an option because I use `geom_boxplot`?

Comment: `coord_cartesian` is still an option with `geom_boxplot` or other geoms.

Comment: Yes, but can't figure out how to do horizontal boxplots since that requires `coord_flip` and you can't have two coords.

Comment: Never mind, you can set the ylim's in `coord_flip` instead of `coord_cartesian` in that case.

Answer (score 4):

Just for completness here is the visual guide to this behaviour:

```
df <- data.frame(
  trt = c( 2, 3, 3.8, 5, 6),
  resp = c( 2.5, 3, 3.8, 3, 3.8),
  upper = c( 3, 3.3, 4.5, 3.3, 4.5),
  lower = c( 2, 2.4, 3.4, 2.4, 3.4)
)

p <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = df, 
                aes(x = trt, 
                    y = resp)) +
  geom_errorbar(data = df, 
                aes(x = trt, 
                    y = resp, 
                    ymin = lower, 
                    ymax = upper), 
                width = 0) +
  coord_flip() +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(plot.margin = margin(0.5, 3, 0.5, 0.5, "cm"))

p
```

[image]

```
p + 
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

```
p + 
  coord_flip(ylim = c(1, 4))
```

[image]

```
p + 
  coord_flip(ylim = c(1, 4),
             clip = 'off')
```

[image]