# Zooming the ggplot or normal plot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, zooming

I am trying to zoom the plot that I have got. But i couldn't find any proper result. Here is my original [plot](http://s11.postimg.org/cwsm4ruyb/Screenshot_1.png)!

```
plt <- ggplot(Df, aes(x = Lon, y = Lat, colour = AC), pch = 17) +geom_point()
plt + geom_path(arrow= arrow(), colour="grey") + scale_size(range = 1)
```

I have tried to do it using dygraph, zoom packages but couldn't succeed. 
**Note** that I do not want to use xlim and ylim over here.

Comment: If you do not want to use xlim or ylim, please define what you do mean by zooming.

Comment: @Axeman i mean, if u can see the graph, it is very dense at different points. xlim and ylim does give me zoomed plot but its only for a section not for the whole graph. I want to zoom the whole plot not just the section

Comment: Do you mean saving the plot in a larger resolution / size? You could use `ggsave` and play around with the  `width` and `height` parameters.

Comment: is this [answer by Tyler Rinker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom) what you are looking for?

Comment: @RHA yes, i kind of looking for that.. But its not exactly what I am looking for. how do I zoom the whole graph. its given only for the ylim ?
I want to zoom the whole graph. like as google earth does.

Comment: So if i'm correct you want to have the whole graph, but be able to zoom in and out on the areas with dense points? Then the best option i know is to make your points smaller and save it to vector format (for example pdf) with high resolution. Then you can zoom in and out with acrobat reader.

Comment: @RHA isn't there similar any option in R?

Comment: Ah, you just want to be able to zoom in and out in the window where R displays the graph. As far as i know, that is not possible. R-studio has a zoom function, but it is limited. However, there is a possibility in R studio, that i think will suit you're needs. I will add that as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

If i understand correctly, you want to zoom in and out in the graphics device (window) and not zoom the plot itself, as is shown here [Limit ggplot2 axes without removing data (outside limits): zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom)

Probably you're best bet is still the `zoom` package. This package has several functions that may be useful to you, like `inout.zoom()` and `sq.zoom()`. If this doesn't work for you, please be more specific of what it doesn't do.

`R-studio` offers some options:
1. There is a zoom button above the plot window, that shows the graph in a bigger window. I some cases this will be enough, however in your case it will not be because you have many points cluttered together.
2. In `R-studio`, press EXPORT-SAVEtoPDF-PREVIEW. This will open a preview in acrobat reader where you can zoom in and out as much as you like.

Comment: thank you for the answer. It could be one of the method but it'll be hard to find the points exact position after zooming the image.
Isn't there any way that I can scale up or scale down my plot(axis) when i zoom in or zoom out?

Comment: Then i think you should be looking at the zoom package (again), see my edited answer. If that doesn't work for you, please specify what it doesn't do.

Answer (score 0):

What I do in this case is render it additionally to a png file at high resolution and then I can examine it with other tools at my leisure. Code with filename and 1000x1000 resolution is like this:

```
   gfname <- sprintf("plotname-%d.png",version)
   png(gfname,width=1000,height=1000)
   print(plt)
   jnk <- dev.off()
```

Comment: It's easier to use `ggsave` to write ggplots to a file.

Comment: I didn't see that I could control image size in pixels - at least directly - with `ggsave`. I normally use it otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

```
ggsave(p,filename=mypath,width=13.66,height=7.05,limitsize = FALSE)
```

worked for me in getting the zommed plots saved within a loop.
p- plot