# Color horizontal bars in ggplot's geom_bar

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm having some trouble with `ggplot2`'s `geom_bar`:

Here's my data:

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(log10.p.value = -10*log10(runif(10,0,1)), y = letters[1:10], col = rep("#E0E0FF",10), stringsAsFactors = F)
#specify color by log10.p.value
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 2)] <- "#EBCCD6"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 4)] <- "#E09898"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 6)] <- "#C74747"
df$col[which(df$log10.p.value > 8)] <- "#B20000"
#truncate bars
df$log10.p.value[which(df$log10.p.value > 10)] <- 10
```

As you can see each `log10.p.value` interval is assigned a different color and since I don't want the bars to extend beyond `log10.p.value = 10` I set any such value to 10.

My `ggplot` command is:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value,x=y,fill=as.factor(col)))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2)+coord_flip()+scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10),labels=c(seq(0,7.5,2.5)," >10"))+
  theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10))+scale_fill_manual(values=df$col,guide=FALSE)
```

And the figure is:

[image]

The problems are:

1. The bar colors in the plot do not match `df$col`. For example, bars a and b are colored #EBCCD6 rather than #E09898.
2. Because I manually specify the x-axis last tick text to be ">10" an extra space is created in the plot to the right of that tick making the bars I truncated at 10 seem like they end at 10, whereas my intention was for them to go all the way to the right end of the plot.

Comment: for me it works , why don't you think that it is not matching ? maybe use windows() X11() for linux and quartz() for mac before plotting so you will have a bigger window ? for limiting the plot in ggplot you should use  coord_cartesian as explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom

Comment: Updated my answer to include the correct way of specifying colours through scale_colour_manual. However, your graph is not reproducible, so you will still need to check that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am unable to reproduce the graph that you generated. Running the code you've provided generates the following graph:

[image]

You can correctly specify the colours by naming the vector that you are passing to `scale_fill_manual`:

```
coloursv <- df$col
names(coloursv) <- df$col
```

To the second part of your question - you can make sure there is no space between the bars and the edge of the graph using the `expand` parameter of `scale_y_continuous`.

Making these two changes, the code for the plot becomes:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(y=log10.p.value,x=y,fill=as.factor(col)))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",width=0.2) +
    scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,10),
                       labels=c(seq(0,7.5,2.5)," >10"),
                       expand = c(0,0)) +
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=10)) +
    scale_fill_manual(values = coloursv,guide = F) +
    coord_flip()
```

[image]

The '>10' label is a bit cut-off. You can increase the plot margins to make it visible, using:

```
p + theme(plot.margin=unit(c(0.1,0.5,0.1,0.1),"cm"))
```

[image]