# ggplot ribbon cut off at y limits

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to use geom_ribbon in ggplot2 to draw shaded confidence ranges. But if one of the lines goes outside the set y limits, the ribbon is cut off without extending to the edge of the plot.

Minimal example

```
x <- 0:100
y1 <- 10+x
y2 <- 50-x

ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "x", limits = c(0,100)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = "y", limits = c(-20,100)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x=x, ymin=y2-20, ymax=y2+20), alpha=0.2, fill="#009292") +      
  geom_line(aes(x=x , y=y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=x , y=y2))
```

[image]

What I want is to reproduce the same behaviour as I get with plotting in base R, where the shading extends to the edge

```
plot(x, y1, type="l", xlim=c(0,100),ylim=c(-20,100))
lines(x,y2)
polygon(c(x,rev(x)), c(y2-20,rev(y2+20)), col="#00929233", border=NA)
```

[image]

Comment: using `oob=scales::squish` in the `scale_y_continuous()` call is helpful but creates some of its own artifacts ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit ggplot2 axes without removing data (outside limits): zoom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom)

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The problem is that `limits` is removing all data which are not within its range. 
What you want is to first plot and then zoom in. This can be done by using `coord_cartesian`.

```
ggplot() + theme_bw() +
  geom_ribbon(aes(x = x, ymin = y2 - 20, ymax = y2 + 20), alpha = 0.2, fill = "#009292") +      
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y1)) +
  geom_line(aes(x = x, y = y2)) + 
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(-25, 100), xlim = c(0,100))
```

[image]