# Use ggplot2 to shade the area between two straight lines

Tags: r, ggplot2

First, I initialize the data

```
set.seed(1)
x <- runif(10000,17,18)
yone <- x+1/4
ytwo <- x-1/4
df <- data.frame(x,yone,ytwo)
```

Then I create the plot

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=yone)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=ytwo)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yone, ymax = ytwo),fill='blue',alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=17) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=17) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=18) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=18) +
    theme_bw() +
    scale_x_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(17,18)) +
    scale_y_continuous(expand=c(0,0), limits = c(17,18))
```

[image]

There are two trapezoid shaped areas between the lines that are not shaded. I want it to look like:

[image]

That area is filled in properly if I dont use `scale_x_continuous` and `scale_y_continuous` to restrict the limits of the plot, but that's a necessity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `coord_casterian` instead of `scale_._continous` not to remove some values.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=x)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=yone)) + 
    geom_line(aes(y=ytwo)) +
    geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yone, ymax = ytwo),fill='blue',alpha=0.5) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=17) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=17) +
    geom_hline(yintercept=18) +
    geom_vline(xintercept=18) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(17,18), ylim = c(17,18))
```

[image]

## Additional code

```
df %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(ytwo = max(17, ytwo),
         yone = min(18, yone)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=yone)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=ytwo)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = yone, ymax = ytwo),fill='blue',alpha=0.5) +
  theme_bw() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=17) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=17) +
  geom_hline(yintercept=18) +
  geom_vline(xintercept=18) +
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(17,18), ylim = c(17,18))
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way to exclude the shaded area below Y=17 and above Y=18? Whether that means to not shade that area or not show it in the plot?

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. Just have to add expand=F as a parameter to coord_cartesian and it works. Thanks!

Comment: @Machetes0602 I add the code above. Please check it out.

Answer (score 3):

There is a known bug on Windows that effects the clipping of regions that have alpha values set. See the github issue here: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4498

The recommended work around is to use the AGG graphics device rather than the default Windows graphic device. Those there is a comment that a fix was incorporated into  `r-devel (r81114)` but that was 4 days ago. This bug appears to still be in 4.1.1 but may be fixed in future R versions.

But even without the bug, don't use `scale_x_continuous` to zoom in. Use `coord_cartesian` as described this existing question: [ggplot ribbon cut off at y limits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38777337/ggplot-ribbon-cut-off-at-y-limits)