# R: Making Axis Consistent in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization

I am working with the R programming language.

I generated some random data and added a polynomial regression line to the data:

```
# PLOT 1

library(ggplot2)

x = rnorm(15, 2,2)

y = rnorm(15,7,2)

df = data.frame(x,y)

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y))

p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

#Add a loess smoother

p + stat_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fill=NA, formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),colour="red") + ggtitle("Original Data: Polynomial Regression Model")
```

[image]

Now, I want to add a single outlier to this data, re-fit the polynomial regression and plot the data:

```
# PLOT 2

x = rnorm(1,13,1)

y = rnorm(1, 13,1)

df_1 = data.frame(x,y)

df = rbind(df, df_1)

p <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y))

p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

 #Add a loess smoother

p + stat_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fill=NA,

                formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),colour="red") +  ggtitle("Modified Data: Polynomial Regression Model")
```

**My Problem:** The problem is, now the axis has become so big that the data looks like a "flat line":

[image]

I tried to fix this by limiting the size of the axis:

```
p + stat_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fill=NA, formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),colour="red") +  ggtitle("Modified Data: Polynomial Regression Model")+ scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(df$y),max(df$y)))
```

[image]

But I now get the following warning message:

```
Warning message:
Removed 35 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth).
```

**My Question:** Why are rows being deleted when I try to fix the axis? Is there a better way to correct this problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit ggplot2 axes without removing data (outside limits): zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom)

Comment: Thank you! I was just confused: i dont have 35 rows in my dataset... how is it possible to remove 35 rows!?  :)

Comment: You're welcome. The solution is to use `coord_cartesian()` instead of limits (as suggested in the link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom), but that link doesn't explain where the 'extra' rows come from. It's too difficult to explain in a comment, so I'll post an answer to explain it further

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you fit a `stat_smooth()` (or `geom_smooth()`) curve you are essentially creating data points i.e. you are generating a list of coordinates that the line will follow. When you changed the y axis limits, some of these coordinates ended up outside the limits and were removed. So, it isn't your original 16 points that are outside your limits, it is the 'calculated' coordinates for the `geom_smooth()` line.

Here is an example showing the new 'internal' data created by `stat_smooth()` in the ggplot object ("p2"):

```r
library(ggplot2)
x = rnorm(15, 2,2)
y = rnorm(15,7,2)
df = data.frame(x,y)

p <- ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21,
             fill="blue", colour="black",
             size=5) +
  geom_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fill=NA,
              formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),
              colour="red") +
  ggtitle("Original Data: Polynomial Regression Model")
p
```

[image]

```r
x = rnorm(1,13,1)
y = rnorm(1, 13,1)
df_1 = data.frame(x,y)
df = rbind(df, df_1)

p2 <-ggplot(df, aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, 
             fill="blue", colour="black",
             size=5) +
  stat_smooth(method="lm", se=TRUE, fill=NA,
              formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),
              colour="red") +
  ggtitle("Modified Data: Polynomial Regression Model") +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(min(df$y),max(df$y)))
p2
#> Warning: Removed 37 rows containing missing values (geom_smooth).
```

[image]

```r
ggplot_build(p2)$data[[2]]
#>              x         y     ymin      ymax         se flipped_aes PANEL group
#> 1  -0.23985422  6.710141       NA        NA   2.432118       FALSE     1    -1
#> 2  -0.07381912  6.765093 2.975488 10.554698   1.675217       FALSE     1    -1
#> 3   0.09221597  6.827052 3.150370 10.503735   1.625299       FALSE     1    -1
#> 4   0.25825106  6.891454 3.020561 10.762347   1.711151       FALSE     1    -1
#> 5   0.42428615  6.955375 3.107609 10.803142   1.700928       FALSE     1    -1
#> 6   0.59032125  7.017292 3.429403 10.605180   1.586047       FALSE     1    -1
#> 7   0.75635634  7.076844 3.875816 10.277873   1.415034       FALSE     1    -1
#> 8   0.92239143  7.134617 4.321137  9.948098   1.243716       FALSE     1    -1
#> 9   1.08842652  7.191933 4.663619  9.720246   1.117656       FALSE     1    -1
#> 10  1.25446161  7.250651 4.856861  9.644442   1.058189       FALSE     1    -1
#> 11  1.42049671  7.312991 4.923653  9.702330   1.056221       FALSE     1    -1
#> 12  1.58653180  7.381355 4.924840  9.837869   1.085917       FALSE     1    -1
#> 13  1.75256689  7.458168 4.912355 10.003980   1.125392       FALSE     1    -1
#> 14  1.91860198  7.545735 4.908758 10.182712   1.165691       FALSE     1    -1
#> 15  2.08463707  7.646104 4.911585 10.380623   1.208810       FALSE     1    -1
#> 16  2.25067217  7.760941 4.907110 10.614772   1.261553       FALSE     1    -1
#> 17  2.41670726  7.891421 4.884922 10.897920   1.329041       FALSE     1    -1
#> 18  2.58274235  8.038130 4.847749 11.228511   1.410327       FALSE     1    -1
#> 19  2.74877744  8.200977 4.813006        NA   1.497673       FALSE     1    -1
#> 20  2.91481253  8.379121 4.807386        NA   1.578907       FALSE     1    -1
#> 21  3.08084763  8.570910 4.858931        NA   1.640902       FALSE     1    -1
#> 22  3.24688272  8.773830 4.989796        NA   1.672755       FALSE     1    -1
#> 23  3.41291781  8.984466 5.210253        NA   1.668413       FALSE     1    -1
#> 24  3.57895290  9.198480 5.512992        NA   1.629192       FALSE     1    -1
#> 25  3.74498800  9.410595 5.866693        NA   1.566603       FALSE     1    -1
#> 26  3.91102309  9.614597 6.209727        NA   1.505143       FALSE     1    -1
#> 27  4.07705818  9.803344 6.451282        NA   1.481799       FALSE     1    -1
#> 28  4.24309327  9.968788 6.496294        NA   1.535037       FALSE     1    -1
#> 29  4.40912836 10.102016 6.295586        NA   1.682655       FALSE     1    -1
#> 30  4.57516346 10.193293 5.875238        NA   1.908822       FALSE     1    -1
#> 31  4.74119855 10.232124 5.314615        NA   2.173814       FALSE     1    -1
#> 32  4.90723364 10.207325 4.710764        NA   2.429787       FALSE     1    -1
#> 33  5.07326873 10.107110 4.159409        NA   2.629216       FALSE     1    -1
#> 34  5.23930382  9.919186 3.745953        NA   2.728914       FALSE     1    -1
#> 35  5.40533892  9.630862 3.530453        NA   2.696722       FALSE     1    -1
#> 36  5.57137401  9.229169 3.502837        NA   2.531359       FALSE     1    -1
#> 37  5.73740910  8.700996 3.447417        NA   2.322376       FALSE     1    -1
#> 38  5.90344419  8.033234       NA        NA   2.378236       FALSE     1    -1
#> 39  6.06947929  7.212932       NA        NA   3.159180       FALSE     1    -1
#> 40  6.23551438  6.227470       NA        NA   4.805205       FALSE     1    -1
#> 41  6.40154947  5.064739       NA        NA   7.234080       FALSE     1    -1
#> 42  6.56758456  3.713337       NA        NA  10.414227       FALSE     1    -1
#> 43  6.73361965        NA       NA        NA  14.368943       FALSE     1    -1
#> 44  6.89965475        NA       NA        NA  19.144526       FALSE     1    -1
#> 45  7.06568984        NA       NA        NA  24.794757       FALSE     1    -1
#> 46  7.23172493        NA       NA        NA  31.373858       FALSE     1    -1
#> 47  7.39776002        NA       NA        NA  38.932662       FALSE     1    -1
#> 48  7.56379511        NA       NA        NA  47.516027       FALSE     1    -1
#> 49  7.72983021        NA       NA        NA  57.160715       FALSE     1    -1
#> 50  7.89586530        NA       NA        NA  67.893447       FALSE     1    -1
#> 51  8.06190039        NA       NA        NA  79.728997       FALSE     1    -1
#> 52  8.22793548        NA       NA        NA  92.668271       FALSE     1    -1
#> 53  8.39397057        NA       NA        NA 106.696330       FALSE     1    -1
#> 54  8.56000567        NA       NA        NA 121.780347       FALSE     1    -1
#> 55  8.72604076        NA       NA        NA 137.867491       FALSE     1    -1
#> 56  8.89207585        NA       NA        NA 154.882727       FALSE     1    -1
#> 57  9.05811094        NA       NA        NA 172.726539       FALSE     1    -1
#> 58  9.22414604        NA       NA        NA 191.272557       FALSE     1    -1
#> 59  9.39018113        NA       NA        NA 210.365110       FALSE     1    -1
#> 60  9.55621622        NA       NA        NA 229.816685       FALSE     1    -1
#> 61  9.72225131        NA       NA        NA 249.405299       FALSE     1    -1
#> 62  9.88828640        NA       NA        NA 268.871784       FALSE     1    -1
#> 63 10.05432150        NA       NA        NA 287.916987       FALSE     1    -1
#> 64 10.22035659        NA       NA        NA 306.198879       FALSE     1    -1
#> 65 10.38639168        NA       NA        NA 323.329573       FALSE     1    -1
#> 66 10.55242677        NA       NA        NA 338.872263       FALSE     1    -1
#> 67 10.71846186        NA       NA        NA 352.338062       FALSE     1    -1
#> 68 10.88449696        NA       NA        NA 363.182766       FALSE     1    -1
#> 69 11.05053205        NA       NA        NA 370.803517       FALSE     1    -1
#> 70 11.21656714        NA       NA        NA 374.535386       FALSE     1    -1
#> 71 11.38260223        NA       NA        NA 373.647868       FALSE     1    -1
#> 72 11.54863733        NA       NA        NA 367.341284       FALSE     1    -1
#> 73 11.71467242        NA       NA        NA 354.743103       FALSE     1    -1
#> 74 11.88070751        NA       NA        NA 334.904184       FALSE     1    -1
#> 75 12.04674260        NA       NA        NA 306.794933       FALSE     1    -1
#> 76 12.21277769        NA       NA        NA 269.301428       FALSE     1    -1
#> 77 12.37881279        NA       NA        NA 221.221573       FALSE     1    -1
#> 78 12.54484788        NA       NA        NA 161.261789       FALSE     1    -1
#> 79 12.71088297        NA       NA        NA  88.038458       FALSE     1    -1
#> 80 12.87691806 11.047284 5.267979        NA   2.554776       FALSE     1    -1
#>    colour fill size linetype weight alpha
#> 1     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 2     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 3     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 4     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 5     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 6     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 7     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 8     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 9     red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 10    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 11    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 12    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 13    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 14    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 15    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 16    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 17    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 18    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 19    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 20    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 21    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 22    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 23    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 24    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 25    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 26    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 27    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 28    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 29    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 30    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 31    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 32    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 33    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 34    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 35    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 36    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 37    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 38    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 39    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 40    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 41    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 42    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 43    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 44    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 45    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 46    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 47    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 48    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 49    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 50    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 51    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 52    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 53    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 54    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 55    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 56    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 57    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 58    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 59    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 60    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 61    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 62    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 63    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 64    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 65    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 66    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 67    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 68    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 69    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 70    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 71    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 72    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 73    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 74    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 75    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 76    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 77    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 78    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 79    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
#> 80    red   NA    1        1      1   0.4
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-17 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your model has a very wide confidence band. You made the confidence band invisible by setting `fill = NA`, but it’s still "there" and expanding the y axis limits.

Your attempt to "fix" this by limiting the range ends up cutting off part of the regression line, too. Instead, turn off the confidence band by setting `se = FALSE`:

```
p <- p + geom_point(alpha=2/10, shape=21, fill="blue", colour="black", size=5)

p + stat_smooth(
    method="lm", 
    se=FALSE, 
    formula=y ~ poly(x, 6, raw=TRUE),
    colour="red"
  ) + 
  ggtitle("Modified Data: Polynomial Regression Model")
```

[image]