# ggplot warnings - Removed xx rows containing missing values (geom_col)

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have below `ggplot`

```
library(ggplot2)
library(quantmod)
dat = data.frame(x = as.yearqtr(seq(as.Date('2002-01-01'), length.out = 17, by = '95 day')),
                    y2 = c(19747, 19343, 19007, 18336, 17534, 16548, 15536, 14400, 13428, 12686, 11877, 11250, 10625, 10122, 9740, 9314, 8892))

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = y2), fill = 'red') +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(dat$x[1], dat$x[17]))
```

While this is working fine, I am getting below warning

```
Warning message:
Removed 2 rows containing missing values (geom_col).
```

So basically, `ggplot` is removing first and last observations. Is there any way to retain them forcefully while keeping the present layout?

Answer (score 2):

You can remove `scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(dat$x[1], dat$x[17]))` to make it work.

If you wish to keep the `scale_x` function, then one of the very low-level solution is to play around with your `limits` argument. Just add a little bit of padding to the `limits` to expand it.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(dat, aes(x = x)) +
  geom_col(aes(y = y2), fill = 'red') +
  scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(dat$x[1] - 0.1, dat$x[17] + 0.4))
```

[image: limits_padding]

Comment: While this is working, I am wondering if there can be some other way without adding artificial padding at left and right sides. Is it possible to show may be partially the leftmost and rightmost bars without extending the axis?

Comment: Or may be, making the leftmost bar as left aligned and rightmost bar as right aligned. All middle bars stay as-is i.e. centre aligned. Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: @BrianSmith You can replace `scale_x_yearqtr(limits = c(dat$x[1] - 0.1, dat$x[17] + 0.4))` with this line of code `coord_cartesian(xlim=c(dat$x[1], dat$x[17]))` , this set limits successfully without needing to play around with other parameters, see more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom) :)