# geom_boxplot whisker length changing when changing y-axis scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

The length of `geom_boxplot()` whisker shrinks when changing the y-axis scale and removing outliers. How can I make sure the whiskers do not shrink?

In the example below, the first plot shows all the data, inclusive of outliers. For `cyl` = 4, the upper whisker extends to `mpg` = 45. Similarly, the lower whisker for `cyl` = 8 extends to `mpg` = 11

In the second plot, the outliers are removed using `outlier.shape = NA` and the y-axis range is reduced. However, for `cyl` = 4 the upper whisker is now `mpg` = 34 and the lower whisker for `cyl` = 8 is now `mpg` = 13. I would expect the upper whisker for `cyl` = 4 to still be `mpg` = 45 and the lower whisker for `cyl` = 8 to still be `mpg` = 11.

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

# Load the mtcars dataset
data(mtcars)

data <- mtcars %>%
  select(mpg,cyl)

# Add outliers to specific groups
outliers <- data.frame(
  mpg = c(45,50,55,45,50,55),
  cyl = c(4,4,4,8,8,8))

# Create example dataset
data <- rbind(data, outliers)

# Upper whisker length for cyl = 4 is at 45 mpg
# Lower whisker length for cyl = 8 is at 11 mpg
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot()
```

[image]

```r
# Remove outliers and reduce y-axis scale
# Upper whisker length for cyl = 4 is at 34 mpg
# Lower whisker length for cyl = 8 is at 13 mpg
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0,45,5), limits = c(0,45))
#> Warning: Removed 4 rows containing non-finite values (`stat_boxplot()`).
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: The whiskers are shortened due to you removing the outliers. This is a stats rule. By removing the outliers, you are focusing on the bulk of the data and eliminating those extreme values which distorts the visualization of the distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By setting your limit to `45` you are actually removing any data outside of this range, resulting in a shorter plot.

You can tell by setting `breaks = seq(0,55,5), limits = c(0,55)` will keep your whisker ending at 45.

If you'd like to keep the plot between 0 and 45 you can use the function `coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))` as in:

```
data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = factor(cyl), y = mpg)) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.shape = NA) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim=c(0, 45))
```

Please see [Limit ggplot2 axes without removing data (outside limits): zoom](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685185/limit-ggplot2-axes-without-removing-data-outside-limits-zoom) for complete explanation.