# Set tick mark intervals

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to get tick marks with labels for intervals at 10 instead of 20 as shown in the image below - how to get tick marks with labels at intervals of 10 for x-axis and intervals of 5 for y-axis

The original x axis vector has data like [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60] for all series and y-axis vector has data like [1.67, 3.3, 5, 6.67, 8.3,10] for one series and like-wise for other two series.

[image: ggplot below]

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I advise you to add some of your code, so that it is easier for people to help you here.

To answer your question, you could use the `breaks` option in the `scale` family. For instance,

```
g <- ggplot(...) + ...
g + scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(10, 60, by = 10))
  + scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0, 10, len = 5))
```

Comment: It would be nice if there is a way to specify the frequency of breaks, w/o having to specify the upper end point.

Comment: A solution exists using `scales` package [see example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27911053/11494541)