# How can I create a graph in R from a table with four variables? (Likert scale)

Tags: r

I have been really struggling to create a bar chart in R, in which I could present responses to questionnaire questions that use a five point Likert scale.
Considering that 1-Not familiar; 2- Somewhat familiar; 3-Neutral; 4-Familiar; 5-Very familiar. I have created chart in Excel, which looks like this:

[image: Likert scale questionnaire responses]

I am stuck in R with the table below:

```
 [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
row1    3   10    1    8    7
row2    3    6    3    4   13
row3    3    6    3    4   13
row4    2    5    1   10   11
```

Can anyone help me to create similar table in R?
Please.

Comment: [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
row1    3   10    1    8    7
row2    3    6    3    4   13
row3    3    6    3    4   13
row4    2    5    1   10   11

Comment: See the examples under `?barplot`, specifically the 8 lines of code starting about 9 lines down (at the line `mp <- barplot(VADeaths) # default`, and ending with `title(main = "Death Rates in Virginia", font.main = 4)`) ... If you copypaste those 8 or so lines, you'll get something very like the plot you're trying to generate (but on built in data). Note that `VADeaths` is a matrix with named rows and columns.

Comment: I find this barplot rather hard to read and would prefer the centered stacked barplots that the `likert` package produces. It's on CRAN and comes with nice and easy-to-use examples.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

```
    row1<-c(3,10,1,8,7)
    row2<-c(3,6,3,4,13)
    row3<-c(3,6,3,4,13)
    row4<-c(2,5,1,10,11)

X<-rbind(row1, row2, row3, row4)
    barplot(X, plot=TRUE, beside=TRUE, col=1:5, legend=c("Strongly Agree", "Agree", "Neutral", "Disagree", "Strongly Disagree"))
```

Comment: Thank you, I have tried this and that's what Im getting:

Comment: Error in barplot(X, plot = TRUE, beside = TRUE, col = 1:5, legend = c("Strongly Agree",  : 
  object 'X' not found

Comment: Sorry.  I left out the rbind statement.  I've added it now.  You'll want to play with the axis labels and legend placement a bit, but that's the basic code.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a `ggplot2`**-based solution**, as an *alternative* to suggested *base `R` graphics* solution, I think that it should be along the following lines. A *minimal reproducible example (MRE)*, based on your data follows.

```
if (!suppressMessages(require(ggplot2))) install.packages('ggplot2')
if (!suppressMessages(require(reshape))) install.packages('reshape')
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape)

myData <- data.frame('Gov. agencies' = c(3, 10, 1, 8, 7), 'Local authority' = c(3, 6, 3, 4, 13), 'Police forces' = c(3, 6, 3, 4, 13), 'NGO/third sector' = c(2, 5, 1, 10, 11), response = c('Not familiar', 'Somewhat familiar', 'Neutral', 'Familiar', 'Very familiar'))

levels(myData$response) <- c('Not familiar', 'Somewhat familiar', 'Neutral', 'Familiar', 'Very familiar')

myDataMelted <- melt(myData, id.vars = 'response')

ggplot(myDataMelted, aes(x=response, y=value, fill = variable))+
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black")
```

**The result:**

[image]

**WARNING!** Please note that the above code is posted as a *proof-of-concept* and it is not only *not complete* in terms of labeling/beautification, but it contains an *error* (I think, not a major one), which I hope more knowledgeable people here will help me to fix, so that you could have an alternative solution (and I could have some educational experience and peace of mind, after all the trouble :-). The error is that groups are not in the correct order / do not belong to the correct categories. I've tried to alleviate that problem via `levels()`, but probably still missed or forgot some other point.

Comment: Thank you, Im getting two errors:   myDataMelted <- melt(myData, id.vars = 'response')
Error: could not find function "melt"
> 
> ggplot(myDataMelted, aes(x=response, y=value, fill = variable))+
+     geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", color = "black")
Error: could not find function "ggplot"

Comment: @M_Gal: No problem. You're welcome. Let's hope that people will help in fixing the above-mentioned issue.

Comment: Hi, do you know if its possible to change the scale into more accurate?

Comment: @M_Gal: What do you mean: more _tick marks_ or _zoom into_ a plot area? In any case, [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11335836/2872891) contains excellent answers on both questions. Hope this is helpful.