# Ticks of colorbar in R

Tags: r, legend, colorbar

I am using `image.plot` to generate images, and I have a colorbar generated, with ticks located at values 0,500,1500 and 2000.

What I would like is to have ticks located at values 300, 500, 900, 1000, 1500, 1600 and 2000. Can I realize this in R?

Comment: Yes, you can realise this in R. See this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks-in-ggplot2) on number of ticks in ggplot.

Comment: From which package comes `image.plot`?

Comment: @Pgibas Thanks, but I mean the ticks of colorbar... not the axis.....is there anyway to do  this?

Comment: @Pascal just the very basic packages, I don't use any additional ones.

Comment: There is no `image.plot` in basic packages. And `image` doesn't produce a colorkey.

Comment: @Pascal from field https://www.image.ucar.edu/GSP/Software/Fields/Help/image.plot.html, and is there any solution?

Comment: It seems not that easy. How other alternative such as `lattice` or `ggplot2`?

Comment: @Pascal ggplot2 can seems I have to turn to it..Thank you~