# How to change ggplot axis tick markings?

Tags: r, ggplot2

While using ggplot in R, how does it mark the value for the ticks in the x and y axis? My x-axis data is from -4 to 5, but all the ticks are not getting marked in the plot. It just marks -4, 0 and 4.

Comment: add a minimal example and have a search of the documentation (hint: try `scale_x_continuous`)

Comment: scale_x_continuous(breaks=-4:5)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Increase number of axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose this is your raw data:

```
test <- data.frame(-4:5, 1:10)
names(test) <- c("x","y")
```

The default plot looks like this:

```
p1 <- ggplot(test, aes(x,y)) + geom_point()
p1
```

You can then use `scale_x_continuous` to change the tick markings:

```
p1 +  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-4,5, by = 1))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Vishal I'm glad to hear that. It your problem is solved, please give my answer a checkmark to save others' time.