# ggplot2 Skips tick values on the x-axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plotted some data in a scatterplot using:

```
  ggplot(inp) +
    geom_point(mapping = aes(x = x, y = y, color = Level)) +
    coord_fixed() +
    xlim(30, 97) +
    ylim(28, 87) +
    theme_bw()
```

Gives me the following resulting graph:

[image: Graph]

There is enough space to show all x-ticks, but it skips every other 10-increment. How do I get it to show all values on the x-ticks?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase number of axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks)

Comment: I think I can work something out with that! Thanks.