# How to customize the axis of a ggplot graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

[image]

Currently, the y axis value is `(0, 0.05, 0.10, 0.15, 0.20...)`,

I want the axis value to be `(0.7, 0.75, 0.80, 0.85, 0.90, ...)`

How to accomplish this?

Comment: Would this help? [Increase number of axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks)

Comment: Use `scale_y_continuous()` and set the `breaks=` parameter to specify where you want axis labels to appear.

Answer (score -1):

Try this defining a sequence of values inside `scale_y_continuous()`. Here and example using dummy data:

```
library(ggplot2)
#Data
df <- data.frame(Val=runif(100,0.7,1.5),
                 Group=sample(c('a','b','c'),size = 100,replace = T),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=Group,y=Val,color=Group))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = seq(0.7,1.5,by=0.05))
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: `stringsAsFactors` is no longer needed for calls to `data.frame`, as it defaults to `FALSE` in recent versions of `R`.

Comment: scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,0.05,0.10,0.15,0.2))