# Want sequence in intervals of 10 in ggdistribution plot

Tags: r, sequence

A very simple and possibly stupid question, but how can I get intervals of 10 in my code? I have tried everything and cannot seem to get this. I want the intervals to be specifically in the plot that comes from the code below so that the horizontal axis shows intervals of 10.

Here is my code. I want there to be intervals of 10 from the lower limit to upper limit.

```
library(ggfortify)
ggdistribution(dnorm, seq(-50,40,0.1), mean= -15, sd= 10, fill = "blue")
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase number of axis ticks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11335836/increase-number-of-axis-ticks)

Comment: Yes, I updated the question. It was a editing mistake from my side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try adding `scale_x_continuous` :

```
library(ggfortify)
library(ggplot2)

ggdistribution(dnorm, seq(-50,40,0.1), mean= -15, sd= 10, fill = "blue") + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(-50, 30, 10))
```

[image]

Comment: The ` -> tmp` part seems like a mistake--the code as written won't produce this chart

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I was trying something else and copy-pasted that here. Corrected the answer.